# How to add a CA certificate to my dotnet server

Tags: c#, .net, certificate

```js
var certPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "cert.pfx");
var cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath, "123");
var caCertPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "ca.crt");
var caCert = new X509Certificate2(caCertPath);

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
{
    options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 2000, ListenOptions =>
    {
        ListenOptions.UseHttps(cert);
        
    });
});
```

```js
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");

const server = https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync("./key.pem"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("./cert.pem"),
  ca: fs.readFileSync("./ca.crt"),
});

server.on("request", (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
  res.end("Hello, world!");
});

server.listen(8000);
```

How to add a CA certificate to my dotnet server? I add the server certificate, but I didn't find anything about adding a CA certificate, with nodejs I can, but with dotnet I really can't find anything about this with dotnet

Comment: The CA cert should be loaded into the Trusted Root CA store, then it will pick it up automatically.

Comment: @Charlieface it should also be isntalled in the client

Comment: @Cleptus Goes without saying, otherwise it will get Unverified Certificate errors. I was talking about the server.

Comment: @Charlieface 
I did this, but is there any way to check if the certificate is working?

Comment: Connect to the server using a browser, and examine the certificate eg https://www.howtogeek.com/292076/how-do-you-view-ssl-certificate-details-in-google-chrome/

Comment: @Charlieface It worked, thanks.